# Can´t connect to svn behind firewalled proxy using linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, svn, ssh, putty

I have windows 7 and Ubuntu 12 installed on same machine, and using eclipse.

My computer is in a novell network behind a proxy and svn server is in another network behind another proxy. I use putty to connect to svn through a tunnel. And it works in windows, but not in Linux. Both eclipse proxy settings are the same.

Also, in linux, I can connect to remote server using putty, but when I use ssh, can´t stablish connection.

In Putty, settings are:

```
Hostname: 192.168.0.3 
Tunnel: L22 localhost:22
proxy: remoteproxy Port 8283
```

Tried to execute ssh:

```
ssh -L 8283:remoteproxy:22 192.168.0.3
ssh -L 22:remoteproxy:8283 192.168.0.3
```

And it´s not worked.

Even logging with putty and trying connect to svn from eclipse doesn´t work on linux but on windows it´s ok.

Someone can help me?

I followed Fabien instructions, but it did not work. In another terminal I executed a netstat and the following appeared:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State  
tcp 0 1 10.0.40.106:39108 192.168.0.3:ssh SYN_SENT  
tcp 0 0 10.0.40.106:55637 10.0.1.3:3128 ESTABLISHED  
tcp 0 0 10.0.40.106:55700 10.0.1.3:3128 TIME_WAIT  
tcp 0 1 10.0.40.106:56876 91.189.94.25:http SYN_SENT
```

Comment: What's the address of the svn server ?

Comment: The local address is 192.168.0.3
It's behind an webproxy named proxy.blabla.com.br

Comment: And what is your computer IP ? where is the ssh server (IP) ?

Comment: SSH and SVN servers are in the same machine. My machine IP is inet addr:10.0.40.106

Comment: What do these lines correspond to ? `tcp 0 0 10.0.40.106:55700 10.0.1.3:3128 TIME_WAIT  
tcp 0 1 10.0.40.106:56876 91.189.94.25:http SYN_SENT`

Comment: That Synch sent is the SSH connection trying. I can´t precise if the time wait is from same connection. In other words, maybe my connection is passing my proxy and the webproxy is refusing.

Answer (score 0):

The tunnel configuration should be:

`ssh -f -L localport:host:hostport user@ssh_server -N`

In your case:

```
localport=22
host=remoteproxy
user is missing
ssh_server=192.168.0.3
```

For additional info, you may read this [link](http://www.linuxhorizon.ro/ssh-tunnel.html)

Comment: It did not work. In another terminal I executed a netstat and the following appeared

    <code Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      1 10.0.40.106:39108       192.168.0.3:ssh         SYN_SENT
tcp        0      0 10.0.40.106:55637       10.0.1.3:3128           ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.40.106:55700       10.0.1.3:3128           TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      1 10.0.40.106:56876       91.189.94.25:http       SYN_SENT />

Comment: By the way, must I leave local proxy settings? I know that in the firewall here the access is granted only through pptp. I use my proxy settings 10.0.1.3:3128

Comment: Your network topology becomes unclear. Can you restate it ? Something like: machine A (IP) to machine B (IP) via (protocol:port) ...

Comment: I´m using a machine with local ip 10.0.1.x in a Novell network behind a proxy 10.0.1.3. I want to access a network 192.168.0.x behind a webproxy with internet ip 200.210.x.x

Comment: I use port 3128 in my local proxy to access port 8283 from webproxy 200.210.x.x because machine 192.168.x.x doesn´t accept external ssh connections.

Comment: I found a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478498/how-can-i-setup-subversion-with-ssh-tunnel-in-eclipse). It may help.